# Python ADO + ODBC function

Tags: python

I am writing a small module to help a transfer from M$-Access to SQLite (database needs to be portable), but I'm struggling in interpreting the error message that follows from this code (and of course to get it to work).

```
import pyodbc
import win32com.client

def ado(db, sqlstring='select * from table', user='admin', password=''):
    conn = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Connection')
    DSN = ('PROVIDER = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE = ' + db +  ';')
    conn.Open(DSN)
    rs = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Recordset')
    rs.Open(strsql, conn, 1, 3)
    data = rs.GetRows()
    conn.Close()
    return data

def odbc(db, sqlstring='select * from table', user= 'admin', password=''):
    """Create function for connecting to Access databases."""
    odbc_conn_str = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s' % (db, user, password)
    conn = pyodbc.connect(odbc_conn_str)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(strsql)
    data = list(cur)
    conn.close()
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__': # Unit test       
    db = r'C:\pyodbc_access2007_sample.accdb'
    sql="select * from Customer Orders" ## tables: 'Customer Orders', 'Physical Stoks','Prodplans'
    data1 = ado(db,sql)
    data2 = odbc(db,sql)
```

From the ado function I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/pyodbc_access2007_example.py", line 27, in <module>
    data1 = ado(db,sql)
  File "C:/pyodbc_access2007_example.py", line 7, in ado
    conn.Open(DSN)
  File "<COMObject ADODB.Connection>", line 3, in Open
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 282, in _ApplyTypes_
    result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft JET Database Engine', u"Unrecognized database format 'C:\\pyodbc_access2007_sample.accdb'.", None, 5003049, -2147467259), None)
```

and from the odbc function I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/pyodbc_access2007_example.py", line 28, in <module>
    data2 = odbc(db,sql)
  File "C:/pyodbc_access2007_example.py", line 17, in odbc
    conn = pyodbc.connect(odbc_conn_str)
Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Cannot open database '(unknown)'.  It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt. (-1028) (SQLDriverConnect); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General Warning Unable to open registry key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x18c0 Thread 0xe70 DBC 0x379fe4 Jet'. (1); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General Warning Unable to open registry key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x18c0 Thread 0xe70 DBC 0x379fe4 Jet'. (1); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General Warning Unable to open registry key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x18c0 Thread 0xe70 DBC 0x379fe4 Jet'. (1); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General Warning Unable to open registry key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x18c0 Thread 0xe70 DBC 0x379fe4 Jet'. (1); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Cannot open database '(unknown)'.  It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt. (-1028)")
```

Any good idea's on how to read this?

Comment: I think this best fits stackoverflow. From the FAQ, `Trouble-shooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets` is off-topic. You should post code that works but that you think needs review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string only recognizes mdb access files.  There is a connection string that will do mdb and accdb files in pyodbc.

Comment: James, you are actually pretty close.

The required changes should include *.accdb, so that


odbc_conn_str = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=%s;Uid=%s;Pwd=%s;' % (db, user, password)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Customer Orders
----------------------^
```

Having spaces in table names like that, does that really work in Access?
For MSSQL Server I'd quote it like in 
[Customer Orders]

Answer (score 0):

For accessing accdb files, you need to install AccessDatabaseEngine.

Also, be aware if you need 32 or 64 bits!